# HTML table does not line up as expected

Tags: html, html-table

I have created a PHP application that presents a web page based on livestream chat activity.  It's not lining up properly.

The problem is that the "title" (which in this example says "This is where the livestream title should be") should consume all of the Author and Mod areas, and reach into the beginning of the "messages" area (which was created with colspan=2 for that purpose), but instead it stops at the Mod column.  I'm using colspan to control this, and colspan does not seem to be doing what I expect.  I have tried this with Chrome on several platforms, and with latest Safari on iOS... all with the same result.

Put another way, to be sure it's clear, the issue I see, is on the red-colored line.  I expect the title to dip into the Messages area, with the URL immediately next to it, and not to stop at the Mod column.  Also, if one looks closely, that Mod column heading doesn't exactly align on the right side with the values below it, and that's probably a result of the same problem.

I can usually do arithmetic pretty reliably up to 5, but in this instance the computer and I disagree about what 2+3 adds up to.  Any idea what I must do in order to resolve this?

[image: sample browser page]

```css
headingLink {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.freeze-table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

thead th {
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
  background-color: #666;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 20;
  min-height: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: left;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 0 5px;
  font-name: Courier;
  font-size: 12;
  outline: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: none;
  outline-offset: -1px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

tr {
  min-height: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}

pageElement {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.fit {
  /* set relative picture size */
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.center {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.imgbox {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
}

.center-fit {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100vh;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan=2 style='text-align:center;font-weight:bold;'>&nbsp;Date/Time&nbsp;</th>
      <th style='font-weight:bold;'>Author</th>
      <th style='font-weight:bold;text-align:center;'>Mod</th>
      <th colspan=2 style='font-weight:bold;'>Message</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan=2 style='text-align:center;color:red;font-weight:bold;'>2023-05-14</td>
      <td colspan=3 style='color:red;font-weight:bold;'>2023-05-14 This is where the livesteam title should be</td>
      <td style='text-align:right;'><a href='https://youtu.be/dummy'>https://youtu.be/dummy</a></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td style='text-align:right;color:Black;'>1&nbsp;R</td>
      <td style='text-align:center;color:Black;'>07:21&nbsp;(1:14:21)</td>
      <td style='text-align:left;color:Black;'>Some Watcher</td>
      <td style='text-align:center;color:Black;'> (Mod)</td>
      <td colspan=2 style='text-align:left;color:Black;'><a href="https://youtu.be/ddummy?t=4461" target="_blank">_</a>&nbsp;Thanks for the concert Brother</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Inline styles are a royal pain, and using them _while you have a stylesheet_ is just foolish. It's repetitive and messy. A few classes for alignment and text styling would really clean up your document.

Comment: Also, `font-name` isn't a valid property, and `12` isn't a valid font size. `pageElement` doesn't exist as an element type. You can see these things in your browser's inspector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table cell calculation is complex and fraught. To resolve your problem you need at least one row with individual column cells to act as a basis for the layout.

You can then hide them with CSS and ARIA attributes (the latter for accessibility).

```css
.dummy-row {
  height: 1px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.freeze-table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

thead th {
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
  background-color: #666;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 20;
  min-height: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: left;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 0 5px;
  font-name: Courier;
  font-size: 12;
  outline: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: none;
  outline-offset: -1px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

tr {
  min-height: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.fit {
  /* set relative picture size */
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.center {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.imgbox {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
}

.center-fit {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100vh;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan=2 style='text-align:center;font-weight:bold;'>&nbsp;Date/Time&nbsp;</th>
      <th style='font-weight:bold;'>Author</th>
      <th style='font-weight:bold;text-align:center;'>Mod</th>
      <th colspan=2 style='font-weight:bold;'>Message</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan=2 style='text-align:center;color:red;font-weight:bold;'>2023-05-14</td>
      <td colspan=3 style='color:red;font-weight:bold;'>2023-05-14 This is where the livesteam title should be</td>
      <td style='text-align:right;'><a href='https://youtu.be/dummy'>https://youtu.be/dummy</a></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td style='text-align:right;color:Black;'>1&nbsp;R</td>
      <td style='text-align:center;color:Black;'>07:21&nbsp;(1:14:21)</td>
      <td style='text-align:left;color:Black;'>Some Watcher</td>
      <td style='text-align:center;color:Black;'> (Mod)</td>
      <td colspan=2 style='text-align:left;color:Black;'><a href="https://youtu.be/ddummy?t=4461" target="_blank">_</a>&nbsp;Thanks for the concert Brother</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="dummy-row" aria-hidden="true">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I have accepted this answer as it solves the issue, with an explanation as to why the issue is solved (though, frankly, it seems to me that this simple arithmetic should not be any challenge at all for a browser.... but seems at least a few are confused by it.)  I'm all for removing complexity and that's what you've done here!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
headingLink {
              color: white;
              text-decoration: none;
            }
        
            .freeze-table {
              border-spacing: 0;
              padding: 0;
            }
        
            thead th {
              top: 0;
              position: sticky;
              background-color: #666;
              color: #fff;
              z-index: 20;
              min-height: 30px;
              height: 30px;
              text-align: left;
            }
        
            tr:nth-child(even) {
              background-color: #f2f2f2;
            }
        
            th,
            td {
              padding: 0 5px;
              font-name: Courier;
              font-size: 12;
              outline: 1px solid #ccc;
              border: none;
              outline-offset: -1px;
              padding-left: 5px;
              white-space: nowrap;
              overflow: hidden;
              text-overflow: ellipsis;
            }
        
            tr {
              min-height: 25px;
              height: 25px;
            }
        
            pageElement {
              display: flex;
              flex-wrap: nowrap;
              align-items: center
            }
        
            * {
              padding: 0;
              margin: 0;
            }
        
            .fit {
              /* set relative picture size */
              max-width: 100%;
              max-height: 100%;
            }
        
            .center {
              display: block;
              margin: auto;
            }
        
            .imgbox {
              display: grid;
              width: 100%;
            }
        
            .center-fit {
              max-width: 100%;
              max-height: 100vh;
              margin: auto;
            }
```

```html
<table>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th colspan=2 style='text-align:center;font-weight:bold;'>&nbsp;Date/Time&nbsp;</th>
                  <th style='font-weight:bold;'>Author</th>
                  <th style='font-weight:bold;text-align:center;'>Mod</th>
                  <th colspan=2 style='font-weight:bold;'>Message</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
        
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan=2 style='text-align:center;color:red;font-weight:bold;'>2023-05-14</td>
        <td colspan=3>
        <table>
        <tr>
                  <td style='color:red;font-weight:bold;'>2023-05-14 This is where the livesteam title should be</td>
                  <td style='text-align:right;'><a href='https://youtu.be/dummy'>https://youtu.be/dummy</a></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </td>
                </tr>
        
                <tr>
                  <td style='text-align:right;color:Black;'>1&nbsp;R</td>
                  <td style='text-align:center;color:Black;'>07:21&nbsp;(1:14:21)</td>
                  <td style='text-align:left;color:Black;'>Some Watcher</td>
                  <td style='text-align:center;color:Black;'> (Mod)</td>
                  <td colspan=2 style='text-align:left;color:Black;'><a href="https://youtu.be/ddummy?t=4461" target="_blank">_</a>&nbsp;Thanks for the concert Brother</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

Have added new `<table>` with two `<td>` (title and link) inside of `<td colspan=3>`

Comment: Answers should contain some explanation, not just a directive to try it. See [answer].

Comment: It's also best if you copy down the snippet from the question and make your changes to demonstration the solution. The snippet wasn't there when you first posted, but it is now.

Comment: Thank you for this.  While it does seem to work, there is no explanation as to why it works.... which leads me to wonder how long it will be before this too proves a problem.  I do appreciate the effort, though, and have given you a bump accordingly for a solution that seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo in the next line:

```
<td colspan=3 style='color:red;font-weight:bold;'>2023-05-14 This is where the livesteam title should be</td>
```

Try to change the **colspan** attribute to 1 as the example below:

```
<td colspan=1 style='color:red;font-weight:bold;'>2023-05-14 This is where the livesteam title should be</td>
```

Comment: That won't solve my problem... I _want_ this item to consume three columns.